# In Oracle JDBC connections, what do 'connect lapse' and 'authentication lapse' mean?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

While trying to connect to an Oracle database, I get the following error:

> SQLRecoverableException: ORA-17002: I/O error: Connection reset by peer, connect lapse 3986 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms.

What do '**connect lapse XXXXms**' and '**authentication lapse XXXXms**' mean?

Comment: It’s terrible English. ‘Lapse’ on its own means ‘fall’. Evidently a clumsy abbreviation for ‘time lapse’.

Comment: This is not something general of JDBC, but specific to Oracle.

Comment: @user207421 [Merriam-Webster entry for _lapse_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lapse), meaning 5: _"a passage of time"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the term "connect lapse" and "authentication lapse" are related to the connection establishment between the database server and your application.

To be very specific,

- **connect lapse:** represents the time it takes to establish a connection to the database server.  This duration includes the time spent initiating the connection, negotiating parameters with the server, and completing the handshake process.

  Here, It took 3986 milliseconds to establish the connection, including the entire process from initiating the connection to completing the handshake.
- **authentication lapse:** represents the time it takes to perform authentication during the connection establishment. During the connection process, the client (your application) and the database server may engage in an authentication step where the server validates the client's credentials or the client authenticates itself to the server.

  Here, the authentication process itself took 0 milliseconds, suggesting that authentication might not be the source of the problem or that the authentication process is extremely fast.
- **Connection reset by peer (ORA-17002):** indicates that the database server terminated the connection unexpectedly. This could be due to network issues, a misconfiguration, or some other problem between the client and the server.

My personal recommendation would be to check the configuration of the database on your application side.

Comment: Can you cite any references?

Comment: Actually I connectted to another DB using the same client DB configuration. I suspect that I have problem in Network layer.